# <SocketError: getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution> & <Timeout::Error: execution expired>

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I am working on the following task to ascertain domain certificate information from urls using the OpenSSL, TCPSocket, & TCP socket libraries. I am currently trying to improve the existing process by using the Thread library to connect to a socket and return information. For the most part, the code seems to be working only in terms of speed. However, I am receiving inaccurate results and I am unsure as to why. I am not well versed with Threads, TCPSockets, or OpenSSL sockets and furthermore I think the combination of these libraries/classes are contributing to these errors. Here is the code that I have so far.

The code below is the class that I use to ping a url and retrive its certificate information.

```
class SslClient
  attr_reader :url, :port, :timeout

  def initialize(url, port = '443', timeout = 10)
    @url = url
    @port = port
    @timeout = timeout
  end

  def ping_for_certificate_info
    context = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
    certificates = nil
    verify_result = nil
    Timeout.timeout(timeout) do
      tcp_client = TCPSocket.new(url, port)
      ssl_client = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.new tcp_client, context
      ssl_client.hostname = url
      ssl_client.sync_close = true
      ssl_client.connect
      certificates = ssl_client.peer_cert_chain_with_openssl_extension
      verify_result = ssl_client.verify_result
      tcp_client.close
    end
    {certificate: certificates.first, verify_result: verify_result }
  rescue => error
    puts error.inspect
  end
end
```

The below code is an abbreviated version of how my code uses the SslClient to record information:

```
    domains.map do |url|
      Thread.new do
        ssl_client = SslClient.new(struct.domain.gsub("*.", "www."), url.scan_port)
        cert_info = ssl_client.ping_for_certificate_info

        if cert_info
          #### Does some if logic for the cert ######
        else
         ###### Does some else logic for the cert, etc. ######
        end
      end
    end.map(&:value)

    #### Do more stuff ######
```

When I run the code as is, I get the following error:

```
#<Timeout::Error: execution expired>
```

If I increase the timeout argument in `SslCient` to something ridiculous like 30 seconds, I then get the following error: `#<SocketError: getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution>`

If I were to get a list of the top 20 websites and run the code with the timeout set to 30, only a few domains will return the SocketError and it ranges from 3 socket errors to roughly 8. However, on an earlier and slower version without Threading, all the domain information checks out clean and accurate. I'm not sure as to why this is.

Could it be possible that the Thread has something to do with this problem? Or maybe I close the connection 'to quickly'? I've tried to explore the code piece by piece and I suspect that the Thread is the problem. However, I'm not sure as to why it would be the problem due to the fact, that I've read that Threads are standard for API/external call work. Does anyone have recommendations I could try to resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: Using timeouts inside Thread object can lead to unexpected behavior, see [here](https://medium.com/@adamhooper/in-ruby-dont-use-timeout-77d9d4e5a001) for example. Try to use timeouts at the TCPSocket level.

Comment: @LyzardKyng thank you for you comment. I did some playing around and I got through this problem by using a gem called Parallel and removing the explicit thread. Now the thing that I'm trying to grasp is how many threads are appropriate. Thank you.